# Chart, Centering Problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am now doing a chart. And I want to position the node A in the middle and keep the other nodes unchanged. However, neither `\begin{center}...\end{center}` nor `\centering` are working. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass{article}
%-----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.5cm,text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process3} = [rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process4} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process5} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process6} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process7} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.0cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process8} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1.0cm, text centered, text width=1cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
%-----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=29.5cm, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm][scale=0.01,anchor=center]
\node (start) [startstop] {\textbf{A}};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=start, yshift=-1cm]{B};
\node (pro2) [process2, right of=pro1, xshift=2.5cm]{C};
\node (pro3) [process3, right of=pro2, xshift=3cm]{D};
\node (pro4) [process4, below of=pro1, yshift=-1cm]{E};
\node (pro5) [process5, right of=pro4, xshift=1cm]{F};
\node (pro6) [process6, right of=pro5, xshift=1cm]{G};
\node (pro7) [process7, right of=pro6, xshift=0.8cm]{H};
\node (pro8) [process8, right of=pro7, xshift=0.08cm]{I};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro1.north);
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro2.north);
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro3.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro4.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro5.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro6.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro7.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro8.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Hello}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please format your code as described [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks).

Comment: i hope its better now

Comment: @DanielChan Actually, it is worse now. Much worse.

Comment: sorry, my internet sucks. what about now ?

Comment: @DanielChan It's fine now.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Your original code says:

```
\node (start) [startstop] {\textbf{A}};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=start, yshift=-1cm]{B};
```

which means place node `pro1` below node `start`. Therefore, it's `B` which is below `A` and not `C`. If you want `C` below `A` place it and then place `B` to the left of `C` and `D` to the right.

By the way, you're loading `positioning` library but using the deprecated syntax `below of = ...` instead of new `below = of ...`.

Please read [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)

I've replaced old by new and the result looks like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%-----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.5cm,text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process3} = [rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process4} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process5} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process6} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process7} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.0cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process8} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1.0cm, text centered, text width=1cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
%-----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=29.5cm, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm][scale=0.01,anchor=center]
\node (start) [startstop] {\textbf{A}};
\node (pro2) [process, below = of start]{C};
\node (pro1) [process2, left = of pro2]{B};
\node (pro3) [process3, right = of pro2]{D};
\node (pro4) [process4, below = of pro1]{E};
\node (pro5) [process5, right = 1mm of pro4]{F};
\node (pro6) [process6, right = 1mm of pro5]{G};
\node (pro7) [process7, right = 1mm of pro6]{H};
\node (pro8) [process8, right = 1mm of pro7]{I};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro1.north);
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro2.north);
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro3.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro4.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro5.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro6.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro7.north);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro8.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Hello}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

You could also read and apply: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I appreciate. One follow up question, is it possible to fix node A in the middle. Because i am trying to narrow down the node distance between B-C and C-D. However, A will move to the side when i change the distance between B-C and C-D.

Comment: @DanielChan I don't understand. If C is below A and distance B-C is equal to distance C-D, A will be in the middle whatever be the distance B-C (C-D).

Comment: i think i got the solution. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

its remind me on tree, so i suggest to draw your chart as tree:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%-----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
%-----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     base/.style = {rectangle, draw, anchor=north,
                    minimum width=25mm, minimum height=10mm, align=center},
startstop/.style = {base, minimum height=1.5cm},
  process/.style = {base, rounded corners},
 process2/.style = {base, rounded corners, minimum size=1cm},
edge from parent/.style = {thick,-stealth},
%
  level distance = 22mm,
  level 1/.style = {sibling distance=42mm},
  level 2/.style = {sibling distance=28mm},
                    ]

\node (start) [startstop]   {\textbf{A}}
    child{ node [base]   {B}}
    child{ node [base]   {C}
        child{ node [process]   {E}}
        child{ node [process]   {F}}
        child{ node [process]   {G}}
        child{ node [process]   {H}}
        child{ node [process2]  {I}}
        }
    child{ node [base]   {D}}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hello}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

note: for nodes styles i use recent syntax for styles. reduce number of styles (most of them in your *mwe* have the same style). the width of obtained chart  is smaller than text width in portrait page orientation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that your image is too large for that space. If every `cm` is replaced by `mm`, then the image is centered.

Comment: still not working. i just want to move node A on top of node C. i am sorry if my question is a bit mis-leading.